# React application shrinking on iPhone

Tags: html, css, reactjs, browser

So when testing in Chrome, I used a Window Resizer to check the viewport sizes and everything looked amazing. After deployment, I ended up getting this:

[image]

The application is ReactJS and is hosted using Nginx on an Ubuntu server (not that that should matter).

styles.css

```
.header-text {
    font-size: 212px !important;
    color: white;
    line-height: 0.8 !important;
}

.subheader-text {
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 44px !important;
}

.content-boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}

.content-box {
    align-self: center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 32px;
    background-color: #27285C;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.content-box-header {
    font-size: 72px !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.content-box-container {
    grid-area: content-box-container;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 32px;
    background-color: #27285C;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    justify-self: center;
}

.content-box-description {
    grid-area: content-box-description;
    justify-self: left;
}

.fullscreen-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
    .header-text {
        font-size: 144px !important;
    }

    .subheader-text {
        font-size: 44px !important;
    }

    .fullscreen-content {
        margin-top: -20px !important;
    }

    .content-box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .content-boxes-container {
        display: flex !important;
        flex-direction: column !important;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .content-box-container {
        align-self: center;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .content-box-description {
        max-width: 80%;
        color: #27285C;
        align-self: center;
        justify-self: left;
        margin-top: -15px;
    }

    .cards-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .image-card {
        margin-right: 0px !important;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 1201px) {
    .header-text {
        font-size: 212px !important;
    }

    .fullscreen-content {
        margin-top: -350px !important;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .content-boxes-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 0.9fr 0.3fr 1.8fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        gap: 0px 0px;
        grid-auto-flow: row;
        grid-template-areas:
            "content-box-container content-box-container content-box-description"
            "content-box-container content-box-container content-box-description";
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }
    .content-box-description {
        max-width:60%;
        color: #27285C;
        margin-top: -50px !important;
    }
    .about-section {
        width: 60% !important;
        text-indent: 64px;
    }    
}

.cards-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.image-card {
    align-self: center;
    width: 532px;
    height: 832px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 45px;
}

.cards-container .picture-card {
    align-self: center;
}

.about-section {
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self: center;
    margin: 45px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'JockeyOne-Regular';
    src: local('JockeyOne-Regular'), url('../layouts/fonts/JockeyOne-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    /* other formats include: 'woff2', 'truetype, 'opentype',
                              'embedded-opentype', and 'svg' */
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: without some code it's difficult to analyse your problem

Comment: @CodeScooper Added my styles.css, as that seems to be the problem.

Comment: it's not enough dont forget that we have to reproduce the bug to have a better vision of what happen, for the moment i see 'content-box' and 'content-boxes' i gess that 'content-boxes' is for all the box , so he have to cover all the screen and receive justify-content:space-around to have all item inside center